# Proving the statement using Resolution?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic, logic-translation

I'm trying to solve this problem for my logical programming class:

> Every child loves Santa. Everyone who loves Santa loves any reindeer.
>   Rudolph is a reindeer, and Rudolph has a red nose. Anything which has
>   a red nose is weird or is a clown. No reindeer is a clown. John
>   does not love anything which is weird. (Conclusion) John is not a
>   child.

Here is my theory:

```
1. K(x) => L(x,s)                  % Every child loves Santa
2. L(x,s) => ( D(y) => L(x,y) )    % Everyone who loves Santa loves any reindeer
3. D(r) & R(r)                     % Rudolph is a reindeer, and Rudolph has a red nose.
4. R(x) => ( W(x) v C(x) )         % Anything which has a red nose is weird or is clown
5. ~( D(x) & C(x) )                % No reindeer is a clown.
6. W(x) => ~L(j,x)                 % John does not love anything which is weird.
7. ?=> ~K(j)                       % John is not a child?
```

Here are the clauses in CNF:

```
1. ~K(x) v L(x,s)
2. ~L(x,s) v ~D(y) v L(x,y)
3. D(r)
4. R(r)
5. ~R(x) v W(x) v C(x)
6. ~D(x) v ~C(x)
7. ~W(x) v ~L(j,x)
8. K(j)
```

I cannot seem to get an empty statement by Resolution. Is there a mistake in my theory or the conclusion indeed does not follow?

**Edit: Resolution**

```
[3,6]   9.  ~C(r)
[4,5]   10. W(r) v C(r)
[9,10]  11. W(r)
[8,1]   12. L(j,s)
[12,2]  13. ~D(y) v L(j,y)
[11,7]  14. ~L(j,r)
[13,14] 15. ~D(r)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Assuming implied universal quantifiers for x and y, L(x,s) => ( L(x,y) & D(y) ) does not seem to say "Everyone who loves Santa loves any reindeer."  Shouldn't D(y) be in the antecedent?

Comment: Your main problem seems to be that you're trying to do predicate logic without bothering to put in the quantifiers.

Comment: ∀x (L(x,s) => ∀y (L(x,y) & D(y))). Then I converted to the  Prenex Normal Form ∀x ∀y(L(x,s) =>  (L(x,y) & D(y))) and removed the universal quantifiers. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Those statements are already in the equivalent CNF (at least I hope so). I am wondering if they are converted right?

Comment: It seems like you are saying that everything is a reindeer.

Comment: @user825089: That says "for every $x$, if $x$ loves Santa then everything is a reindeer loved by $x$".

Comment: @ChrisEagle Thank you! I see the mistake now. Can you please check if it is correct now? I still can't resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion is correct.

I will let you tidy this up and fill in the gaps, but you might want to consider the following

```
W(r) v C(r)
W(r)
~L(j,r)
~L(j,s)
~K(j)
```

Comment: Thank you! If the conclusion is correct, why can't I get an empty statement? Am I doing something wrong in resolving the clauses? Can you please check my edit?